# Как получить данные из контекста

Tags: reactjs

Я пытаюсь создать переключатель свелой на темную тему. У меня есть три файла: Theme-context, где я создаю контекст, Header - где будет кнопка для переключения темы, Content - где тема изменится Я не могу понять, как передать значение темы из файла Header в Content, чтобы тема изменилась. Как это может быть сделано? Спасибо)

Header

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Theme_Context, themes} from "../Contexts/Theme_Context";

export function Header () {

let [theme, setTheme] = useState(themes.light);

let toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((prevTheme) => prevTheme === themes.light ? themes.dark : themes.light)
}

return (<header className="header">
    <button onClick={toggleTheme}>Change Theme</button>
        </header>)
}
```

Theme_Context

```
import React, {createContext} from "react";

export let themes = {
light: {
    background: '#eeeeee',
    textColor: '#444444'
},
dark: {
    background: '#444444',
    textColor: '#eeeeee'
},
};

export let Theme_Context = createContext(themes.light);
```

Content

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {Theme_Context} from "../Contexts/Theme_Context";

export default Content = () => {
return (<div>
<Theme_Context.Provider value={theme}/>
// Content
</Theme_Context.Provider>
</div>)
}
```

Comment: Может вам поможет: https://vc.ru/design/137715-kak-sdelat-nochnoy-rezhim-v-react-prilozheniyah

Comment: @highpassion Спасибо большое за помощь, но это задание нужно на контексте сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контексте передаём текущую тему и функцию для её изменения. Далее в любом компоненте который находится внутри `ThemeContext.Provider` можно получить доступ к ним с помощью `React.useContext`. Получается примерно так:

```
import React from "react";

// файл 1
// импортируется там где нужен
export const themes = {
  light: {
    background: "#eeeeee",
    textColor: "#444444",
  },
  dark: {
    background: "#444444",
    textColor: "#eeeeee",
  },
};

// файл 2
// import React from "react";
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

const defaultTheme = "light";

const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(defaultTheme);
  const toggleTheme = () => setTheme(theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light");

  return (
    <div>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={[theme, toggleTheme]}>
        <Header />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;

// файл 3
// import React from "react";
// import { themes } from ...
// import { ThemeContext }  from ...

const Header = () => {
  const [theme, toggleTheme] = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  const colors = themes[theme];

  return (
    <header
      className="header"
      style={{ backgroundColor: colors.background, color: colors.textColor }}
    >
      <h3>Current theme is : {theme}</h3>
      <h3>Background is : {colors.background}</h3>
      <h3>TextColor is : {colors.textColor}</h3>
      <button onClick={toggleTheme}>Change Theme</button>
    </header>
  );
};

// export default Header;
```

Comment: Один вопрос, почему вы здесь используете главную компоненту App. Можно без нее обойтись, для чистоты кода?

Comment: Конечно имя можно использовать любое. Отметьте ответ как правильный если всё работает. Спасибо.